# Decoherence of one-photon states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, decoherence

Let $\rho_1$ be the pure one-photon state described by the ket
$$|\psi_1\rangle = \int dk\ A(k)a^\dagger(k)|0\rangle$$
for a complex amplitude function $A(x)$ and an empty ket $|0\rangle$. This state is obviously coherent, since non-diagonal terms with amplitudes $A(k)A^*(k')$ contribute to the density matrix.

The main tools to describe loss of coherence that I know of are the depolarizing and the dephasing channels. However, most treatments deal only with their application to a qubit state. How does one describe partial decoherence of such a state (preferably, in a calculation-friendly way)?

Comment: Note crosspost https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/798982/291677

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dephasing channel acts on the state $\rho$ as
$$\rho\to \frac{1}{2\pi}\int d\theta e^{i\theta a^\dagger a}\rho e^{-i\theta a^\dagger a}.$$ Here $a^\dagger a$ is the photon-number operator for a particular mode that gets dephased from the rest. You can see that the channel retains components that commute with $a^\dagger a$, because $a^{\dagger l}|0\rangle\langle 0| a^m\to e^{i\theta(l-m)}a^{\dagger l}|0\rangle\langle 0| a^m$. So you can dephase a particular mode from the rest by using
$$\rho\to \frac{1}{2\pi}\int d\theta e^{i\theta a^\dagger(k) a(k)}\rho e^{-i\theta a^\dagger(k) a(k)}$$ to remove terms of the form $|k\rangle\langle k^\prime|$ with $k^\prime\neq k$ from $\rho$. To dephase all of the modes, we need an integral for each $k$:
$$\rho=\int dk_1 dk_2 A(k_1)A^*(k_2)|k_1\rangle\langle k_2|\to \prod_k\frac{\int d\theta_k}{2\pi} e^{i\theta_k a^\dagger(k)a(k)}\rho e^{-i\theta_k a^\dagger(k)a(k)}=\int dk_1 |A(k_1)|^2 |k_1\rangle\langle k_1|.$$ There's probably a fancy way to write this integral over a continuous number of parameters but I don't have it offhand. A partially dephasing channel would mix this channel with an identity channel, such that with probability $p$ this channel is applied and with probability $1-p$ nothing happens to the state.

Completely depolarizing channels replace the state with the maximally mixed state. This is also a challenge with a continuous number of parameters, because that state is an identity matrix over all states and must be normalized:
$$\rho\to \frac{\int d_k a^\dagger (k)|0\rangle\langle 0|a(k)}{\int d_k }=\frac{\mathbb{I}}{\mathrm{Tr}\mathbb{I}},$$ where the denominator goes to infinity. This channel has Kraus operators that take every possible state to every other possible state, so it will look like
$$\rho\to\propto \int dk_1 dk_2 |k_1\rangle\langle k_2|\rho |k_2\rangle\langle k_1|.$$ Again, partially depolarizing channels apply this with some probability $p$.

The overall answer is: the intuition of what happens is the same as for qubits (remove phases or replace with maximally mixed state) but it is harder to be calculation friendly when you are essentially dealing with infinite dimensional matrices, and you have to worry about whether each off-diagonal is dephased to the same extent and how to normalize the overall matrix.

Comment: So, to be explicit, partial decoherence is given by the evolution
$$\rho\to (1-p) \int dk_1dk_2A(k_1)A^*(k_2)|k_1\rangle\langle k_1|+p\int dk |A(k)|^2|k\rangle\langle k|$$
under the action of the dephasing channel, where $p\in[0,1]$ quantifies the amount of remaining coherence?

Comment: @Bentanglement yes ish; that is explicitly partial *dephasing* where the dephasing acts equally on each mode. Yes that is a type of decoherence, but sometimes people mean different things when they say decoherence. You can see how each term $A(k_1)A^*(K_2)|k_1\rangle\langle k_2|$ gets multiplied by $(1-p)+p\delta(k-k^\prime)$; an even more general model that dephases different mode combinations by different amounts could multiply each term by $(1-p(k_1,k_2))+p(k_1,k_2)\delta(k-k^\prime)$ for some function $p(k_1,k_2)$